# Multiple Observables waiting for single Observable completion on RetryWhen

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to build an app using Oauth2.

There are multiple (GET) calls to API from the frontend and I deal with them like so:

```
// Call API for data
this.apiGet('/foo?id=bar).pipe(
  // If it fails, use refresh token to obtain new access token and try again
  retryWhen(x => {
    // If there is existing request (Observable), use it
    if (this.refreshTokenObservable !== null) {
      return this.refreshTokenObservable;
    }

    // Otherwise make new request (fills this.refreshTokenObservable)
    return this.getAccessByRefreshToken();
  })
)
```

This works fine when there is only one `apiGet()`, however, when using multiple calls one right after another, the `refreshTokenObservable` variable do not fill quickly enough, causing multiple calls and, subsequently, errors.

Is there any way to prevent this?